# Can I use AWS Copilot with docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-copilot

I'm trying to implement ECS architecture of my web application on AWS using AWS copilot. But it is asking for Dockerfile as input.

My application has a complex **docker-compose** file with multiple services. Can i somehow use this file for creation of ECS Cluster from copilot?

Thank you.

Comment: Read: https://github.com/aws/copilot-cli/issues/1612

Answer (score 4):

At the moment, no, but please upvote/join the discussion [here](https://github.com/aws/copilot-cli/issues/1612) to share more details of your use case and what you'd like to see!